# Doing a logistic regression on a $2 \times 2$ table, why does R yield a different odds ratio than by hand-calculation?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, odds-ratio

Suppose today I have a $2 \times 2$ table I would like to analyze through logistic regression. The table tells us how many people responded to treatment vs control for headaches.

```
           Headache       No Headache
Treatment          2            10
Control            0             8
```

I did this in R and found the following output:

```
Call:  glm(formula = cbind(c(2,0),c(10,8)) ~ as.factor(c(1, 0)), 
           family = binomial())

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  as.factor(c(1, 0))1  
         -24.92                23.31  

Degrees of Freedom: 1 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
Null Deviance:      2.19 
Residual Deviance: 2.397e-10    AIC: 6.434
```

Now, I understand that the intercept of $-24.92$ is nothing more than the odds ratio when my independent variable is equal to $0$. In other words, its the log of the number of people in Control & Headache divided by Control & No Headache. Hence, it should in theory be equal to:

$$
log\left(\frac{0}{8}\right) = -\infty
$$

But this obviously is not the case. How is R computing the intercept in this case?

Comment: Have you tried doing the calculations by hand and adding 0.5 to every cell? In a 2x2 table when dealing with cells with 0 frequency you can add 0.5 to every cell of the table in order to make a sort of "continuity correction". This prevent you from having results such as infinite or n/0

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do that but R gives me an error that my counts are non-integers since the values are now offset by $0.5$, do you know how to reconcile that?

Comment: Note that $e^{-24.92} \approx 1.5 \times 10^{-11}$, a not-implausible approximation of zero when doing numerical optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `glm` in R is an iterative procedure that uses Newton-Raphson to converge on the estimate and produce covariance estimates. These estimates are divergent, meaning that the actual MLE lies on the boundary of the parameter space. The GLM process will literally never converge if we don't specify some conditions to terminate the procedure. That explains the finite albeit very large log odds ratio in the `glm` procedure. You can't trust the results, and you should have received a warning from R which, in a sense, is the correct answer (or rather caveat) to the data you have supplied.

Answer (score 2):

Count data for discrete independent variables and a discrete dependent variable,  this seems like a good application of Fisher's exact test:

```
fisher.test(cbind(c(2,0),c(10,8)))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  cbind(c(2, 0), c(10, 8))
p-value = 0.4947
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1246093       Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
       Inf
```

Here the odds ratio is matching your hand calculated result.

Comment: That's not the answer to the actual question, and while I agree Fisher's test is a good approach, the reason has to do with the zero.

Comment: Sometimes the question is incorrect for the desired answer.